# Removing a CSRF token from a GET request to a 3rd party API in a Rails + Ember app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ember.js

I am working with a 3rd party API that has the json response I need publicly available at www.whatever.com/index.json, index.json being what I need to grab. In JSbin I have already made it fully functionally just trying to hack it out in a basic fashion to check out how it was functioning before building it into the app. It worked fine and I received the proper response, HOWEVER, in the main application we send a CSRF token with it, and this leads to a 204 no content because it is OUR CSRF token, they do not utilize one for simple GET requests. Is there a trivial way to remove this from the transmission when sending the

```
Ember.$.get(www.whatever.com/index.json)
```

Or will I need to get fancy here?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF tokens aren't automatically injected into your ajax calls.  You're having to hijack the ajax request to inject it, you could just as easily modify that hijack and have it exclude cross site calls.

Here's an example of my csrf hijack, it only does it for our domain

```
// hack to inject the csrf token
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
      var token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", token);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is already being injected via the rails side of things with how the API is built, I need a means to remove it rather than inject one. Is this removing one or adding one? I'm a total noob with this so bear with my dumb questions if you can please :)

Comment: the CSRF token has to be attached to an ajax header being sent, so if it's being attached using rails, then that means rails is injecting some javascript in the page doing something similar to my hack right there.